# replacing hex string using hex editor with larger string

Tags: hex, hex-editors

if i try and replace current hex string with smaller size then its ok but if its longer string then it dont work.

this is an example hex values stored in wireshark file.

```
0000   52 54 00 12 35 02 08 00 27 5e 56 95 08 00 45 00  RT..5...'^V...E.
0010   00 71 59 06 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 00 02 0f 17 13  .qY.@...........
0020   17 3d cb 29 04 38 39 62 a0 3b 01 c9 08 0e 50 18  .=.).89b.;....P.
0030   fa e4 3a c2 00 00 4f 50 54 49 4f 4e 53 20 72 74  ..:...OPTIONS rt
0040   73 70 3a 2f 2f 72 35 2d 2d 2d 73 6e 2d 61 35 6d  sp://r5---sn-a5m
0050   65 6b 6e 6c 36 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 76 69 64 65  eknl6.googlevide
0060   6f 2e 63 6f 6d 3a 35 35 34 20 52 54 53 50 2f 31  o.com:554 RTSP/1
0070   2e 30 0d 0a 43 53 65 71 3a 20 31 0d 0a 0d 0a     .0..CSeq: 1....
```

say i want to replace current string

```
OPTIONS rt
sp://r5---sn-a5meknl6.googlevideo.com:554
```

with something little longer then this area of the code stopps working.
can anybody tell me how to go around doing this.
i open the file using hex editor and use find and replace

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing a packet dump, you most likely need to edit the `TCP` and `Ethernet` headers to increase the packet length. If you're editing a program, replacing with a longer string isn't recommended as you'll have to shift references to items later in the file.